# Call method in main class from static fragment class

Tags: android, class, methods, static, fragment

I have a fragment class and I want to call a method in the "main" class of my activity. The fragment class is static so that is probably whats causing the problem although I have to keep it static. I want to be able to do something like this from inside my static class:
    `Method();`
I've tried:
    `getActivity().Method();`
Although that didn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to cast the activity returned to your specific class to access the public methods.

If your main class is called **MainActivity** and you have some public method **Method** then you could do the following from your fragment method:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).Method();
```

Alternatively you could use the [event callback pattern](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) described in the fragment documention.