# Android login and forgot password - Actvity or fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a login page which will have forgot password right now:

1. Login Page is one `Activity` and Forgot Password page is another `Activity`.
2. Each one calls an `AsyncTask` for http post which returns a `json` response.
3. Hence I have callback listener in each `Activity.
4. In the call back listener I get the `json` response, which I parse in separate `Activity` for each Login and separate one for Forgot password

I need to know whether its good practice to do this way or use `fragments`. Also any other better way to developing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Fragment` per page, so one for "Login" and one for "Forgot Password", and one `Activity` that handles the async http request. You would then be able to use the fragment methods such as `fragment.replace()` to swap out the screens without each fragment having to have a callback listener. The activity then can also parse the callback listener once instead of twice in each separate activity. Also, the way Android is heading, Fragments are better to use for UI elements than separate Activities as it makes UI updates quicker and smoother then starting a new activity.

There is an [Android Developer API Guide loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) available to every Activity and Fragment. Why not check it out. On that same site you can also find guides to use fragments in your activity.

Comment: if I implement fragments, after a button click in fragment how will I let the Activity know that that action is taken place and the activity needs to call the http async task?

Comment: You could do this with a public method inside the activity called by your `onClick()` method of the fragment controlling the buttons in the fragment's layout. There are other ways, but this appears easiest to me.

Comment: @Sweety check out this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment