# How can I use Activity Function In Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm making android project?
I got question. How can I use activity function without extend it. Cause my current java is fragment so I have to extends Fragment. 
Please help.
My code:

```
    public class Tab1fragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * @param argsAc
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_layout, container, false);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: You can use interface concept

Answer (score 1):

You can use like:

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a quick workaround you can use `((YourActivity) getActivity()).yourMethod()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), the official document tells you how to communicate between `Activity` and `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

use it this way :

```
YourActivity myActivity;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    myActivity=(YourActivity)activity;
}
```

and call your activity methods:

```
myActivity.method1();
myActivity.method2(arg0);
```

**OR**

You can use interface implementation which is recommended by android as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

**OR**

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659795/1576416) is a much better answer