# How to call Fragment method from parent activity/Fragment2?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I simply want to call a method declared in fragment through parent activity and it gives me the error " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference"` Please suggest something.

Fragment Method:

```
public void loadSpinnerData() {
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Calling method  from parent actvity:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new NoticeBoard();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Quotes();
        if (fragment instanceof Quotes)
            ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

my logcat is as follows

> Logcat error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference 05-25 08:46:59.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6152): at app.redalkemi.edublaze.Quotes.loadSpinnerData(Quotes.java:210)

Comment: can you show xml file of your parent activity

Comment: it contains android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout with frame and listview

Comment: Quotes fragment = new Quotes();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()..replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

Comment: your fragment should be of android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: this code will on v4 fragment

Comment: And don't forget to take activity as a FragmentActivity in which you are trying to call fragment

Comment: Check this link, you will get your answer,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment

Comment: i have checked the link but it is not helpful as  i replace fragment with beginTransaction() as you can see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your code a little bit

```
    public void loadSpinnerData(Context contxt) {
    Toast.makeText(contxt, "HELLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

in parent activity

```
 if (fragment instanceof Quotes)
        ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData(youractivityname.this);
```

Comment: no it's giving the same error

Comment: post your logcat and mention in which line are you getting the error

Comment: i have posted the logcat please review

Comment: post your updated code with mine and in which line do you get the error??? tell me

Comment: Logcat error : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference 05-25 08:46:59.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6152):  at app.redalkemi.edublaze.Quotes.loadSpinnerData(Quotes.java:210)

Comment: what did u pass in ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData(youractivityname.this); as parameter post the line you tried..

Comment: i didn't pass anything with ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData(youractivityname.this); as paramamerter

Comment: have you used my code???You need to pass your context in  ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData(context) which is equal to  ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData(youractivityname.this);  replace youractivityname with the original activity name of yours

Comment: yes i used your code but it didn't work, can you tell me how to pass context in  ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData(context). I'm totally new to fragment

Comment: you are calling this from your activity right?

Comment: yes  I'm calling this: ((Quotes) fragment).loadSpinnerData(youractivityname.this); from MainActivity

Comment: ohhh... it's not youractivity.this replace it with your classname.ie:the name of your parent activity.

Comment: solve the problem. Thanks...... your really very helpful