# Navigate back from an Activity to fragment of another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity(Activity1) with several fragments. I'm calling a second activity(Activity2) from one of the fragments(say Fragment C) of first Activity. I want to navigate back from the second activity(Activity2) to Fragment C. But, it is navigating to the first fragment of Activity1 instead of Fragment C. Please help.

Block of code I have tried so far:

In Fragment C,

```
categoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),Activity2.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);
        }
        });
```

In the container Activity i.e Activity1,

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        FragmentC myFragment = new FragmentC();

        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, myFragment);
        
        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12659795/4447803 refer this , it may help you

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) the best way to have Fragment to communicate with another even to another Activity is through the associated Activity.

To avoid any mess with Fragment Transaction please referring to this:

> Often you will want one Fragment to communicate with another, for
>   example to change the content based on a user event. All
>   Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FragmentManager to control navigation of fragments and move control back from fragments to previous activity (pop fragments off the back stack).

> In your case you can use popBackStackImmediate() and popBackStack() in fragment manager to destroy fragments.

```
val fragmentManager = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
val isPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
```

or

```
val fragmentManager = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
fragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77295085/17401577) for more details about these methods