# How to access option menu of a activity inside a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, optionmenu

I have an option menu in an activity.

I want to access that menu in a `Fragment` and I want set title for that.

How can I access this?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment.

Answer (score 1):

when overriding the optionsmenu in a fragment a menu reference is passed, this goes through activity's onCreateOptionsMenu first, so you can find and modify the menuItems.

```
@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
          menu.findItem(R.id.shouldModifyinFragment).setTitle("newTitle");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to do this ...... first of all build actionBar in your activity look at the [DOC](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html).!
then change the title like below!

In your Activity:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title){
YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION_BAR_TITLE.setText(title);
}
```

In your Fragment:

```
((yourActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(YOUR_TITLE);
```