# Refresh Activity from ViewPager Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `BaseActivity` which has a `ViewPager` with some `Fragments` in it. In one of these `Fragments` I have 2 buttons which change the language of the app.
The thing I want to accomplish is that, on the click of the button, refresh `BaseActivity` to the selected language but still have the ViewPager set on Settings(name of the fragment). Right now it's reloading the entire app and starts on the fragment which I set it to start on.

**Code for changing the language and refreshing the Activity**

```
 public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        SharedPreferences ensharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("selectedLanguage", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor eneditor = ensharedPreferences.edit();
        eneditor.putString("language", lang);
        eneditor.apply();
        SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(lang,MODE_PRIVATE);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(getContext(), BaseActivity.class);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        startActivity(refresh);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0,0);
    }
```

I have only found methods on doing this the reverse way, to reload a fragment from the activity, but I want to do it the other way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment

Comment: @iMDroid I can't really find the solution to my problem in that thread. I have no need of calling a method from my Activity. I have to restart the activity to change the language(which is implemented), but I don't want it to change the current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the ViewPager's selected position to the Activity using [getCurrentItem()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getCurrentItem()) and pass it to the new Intent as an extra and reselect the item number when relaunching the Activity through getIntent() and move to the previously selected Fragment by using [setCurrentItem(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int))

```
// Restarting the Activity passing the position of the currently selected Fragment
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BaseActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
startActivity(intent);
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   if(intent != null) {
      int position = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Easy and clean solution, thanks!