# How to send two texts to a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have created a tabbed activity with viewpager with two tabs and I want to send two text as title and description from tab one(contains the two edittexts) to tab two(contains the listview).
my fragment_one.java :

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button btnPassData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPassData);
    final EditText inData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inMessage);
    btnPassData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SM.sendData(inData.getText().toString().trim());
        }
    });

}
```

and fragment_two.java :

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

protected void displayReceivedData(String message) {
    arrayList.add(message);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

and my custom_listview is :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#33CC33" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

please guys I need help!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your list view fragment describe method `public void
  setValue(String title, String description)`
- In your first fragment call `((MyActivity)getActivity()).passItToMyBuddy(title, desc);`
- In your activity describe method

{

```
public void passItToMyBuddy(String title, String desc) {
        ((ListViewFragment) listViewFragmentInstance)
                 .setValue(title, desc);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Found much more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment)

Comment: @monzerax you even didn't accept my previous answer to your question