# [Example]dynamic fragments, inter fragment communication,fragment getting re added to screen issue (fragment retention)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So, While learning the basics of android, this word `Fragment` came up at many places like `Navigation Drawers` , `ViewPager` , `PreferencesActivity` , creating a dynamic view , etc . So i started reading about it and turns out this is a very important part of the Android Platform .It enhances the user Experience by allowing apps spread their data across screens of different sizes in a better manner.

For example Apps like Gmail will show their data across multiple "pages" (check the image below for a better idea) on small screen devices, and will show All of their data in a single page in larger devices like Tablets.

[image]
[image]

So the question that usually arisis is "How fragments does that?" and "How does it manages its magical clicks , which changes layout completely when in a small screen device , but simply changes its data , when in a large screen device?" Well This is quite a difficult problem when we think in the aspects of Activity layouts.

So after a little more searches and reading, i was able to successfully learn more about the theory behind fragments,their LifeCycles and static fragments ( [Fragment Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) ) .

What i now wished was to implement some real life application of fragments, like gmail, which comprises of the concept of [adding fragments programmically](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Adding)  . So I devised a small task which helped me in learning the concept of dynamic fragments and fragment-fragment / fragment-activity communication.

**Task**:

- There will be a basic application with 1 `MainActivity` having `LinearLayout` as its root viewGroup.
- 2 Fragments: `FragmentA` (or Frag 1 or Pink background fragment) and `FragmentB` (or frag2/ BlueFragment) will be added to the MainActivity during first run.
- Both Fragment should be able to manipulate the other fragment's visibility for the rest of time, therefore each fragment will have 2 buttons `open Other fragment` and `Close other fragment`.
- On clicking `open frag1` in fragment 2, fragment 1 should be added to screen or do nothing, if already present . Similarly pressing `close frag1` in fragment 2 should be able to remove fragment 1, if  fragment1 is already present or do nothing .

target image samples:

- An activity showing 2 fragments, the pink fragment and the blue fragment(ignore there sizes, was testing `linearlayout#weight`):
  [image: sample3]
- Same activity showing only `fragment1` now , because user pressed `close fragment 2`  inside the `pink fragment` . Thus  layout gets dynamically changed :
  [image: sample]

(Same could be applied for the second fragment too)

**Achievement** : well, after doing this i was able to get a better view of Inter-Fragment communication and i think i now know how those "magical clicks" in Gmail changes data/Layouts in a completely different fragment .

I think it will be unwise to present a set of my all possible failure attempts here , So am just mentioning some of the other problems I faced while solving this task :

**Problems**:
1. Fragments are unable to communicate with each other(a button pressed in fragment 1 is unable to close fragment 2)
2. Fragments gets re-added to the screen multiple times on rotation.
3. Saving display contents: when App is launched, the fragment 1 is being shown by default. During the session,this layout can change to 2 fragments being shown or just the fragment'2' being shown,according to user's input. However , if the user rotates his phone, the content present on the screen is not saved and the activity starts displaying fragment 1 .

Comment: Can this question be reopened ?  @Mike M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 0 :creating a fragment, other files**
create fragment.xml, fragment.java extending fragment and inflate layout in onCreateView().(for both fragments)

```
public class Frag_b extends Fragment {

    public Frag_b() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_b, container, false);
    }

}
```

**step (1) Dynamic Fragments:**
As we know when an app launches, the androidOS first calls the activity to show up(the one having `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` permission ). So to display a fragment in runtime we use a class called FragmentManager(Read more about its features [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html).So, to attach a fragment:
1 - create  **global objects of both the fragments and fragment manager**  in main activity.
2 - create **global fragment tags** : they are very important for restorability of same fragment objects.They will be used as tags to access/ identify strings.
3 - addition via fragment manager: So here comes the first use-case of fragment manager : to add fragments dynamically(at run time). here is the code for it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragAHandler,FragBHandler {
    LinearLayout layRoot;

    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();

    public static  final String FRAG_A_TAG="FRAG_A";
    public static  final String FRAG_B_TAG="FRAG_B";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layRoot=findViewById(R.id.layout_root);
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root,new Frag_a(),FRAG_A_TAG).commit();
        manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root,new Frag_b(),FRAG_B_TAG).commit();

    }

}
```

**step 2 Fragment Communication:**
As indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683615/7500651), fragment communication is a 4 layered process:
 * An interface defines the functions(the task that fragment wants to perform).
 * The activity implements them.
 * The fragment gets an instance of this interface(in the form of activity's context).
 * Fragment uses this instance according to its need .
{in case of fragment-fragment communication , 2 more small steps are added to it}:
 * the fragment sends a signal to activity.
 * the activity then handles the signal and sends it to other fragment.

Thus if a fragment FragA wants the main activity to show notification on a button click(present inside fragment ):

- create an interface FragAcall having function void showNotif().
- Implement it in MainActivity.(and define whatever you wish that your activity should perform on receiving click from fragment A .i.e, showing a notification).
- In fragA create an object of interface FragAcall (FragAcall callObj).
- In fragA, override a method named onAttach(context).cast this context to FragAcall' Object.
- Inside your button's on click listener, call callObj.showNotiff().

similarly for a 2 way fragment-fragment communication, I implemented the code using these steps:
 * created interfaces FragAHandler and FragBHandler:

```
public interface FragAHandler {
    void addFrag1();
    void closeFrag1();
    }
public interface FragBHandler {
    void addFrag2();
    void closeFrag2();
    }
```

- implement these in main activity:

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragAHandler,FragBHandler
  {

  LinearLayout layRoot;
  FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
  public static final String FRAG_A_TAG = "FRAG_A";
  public static final String FRAG_B_TAG = "FRAG_B";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      layRoot = findViewById(R.id.layout_root);
      manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root, new Frag_a(), FRAG_A_TAG).commit();
  }

  @Override
  public void addFrag1() {
      if (manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG) == null) {
          manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root, new Frag_a(), FRAG_A_TAG).commit();
      } else {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag1 Already present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void closeFrag1() {
      Frag_a fragA = (Frag_a) manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG);
      if (fragA != null) {
          manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragA).commit();
      } else {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag1 Already not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }

  }

  @Override
  public void addFrag2() {

      if (manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_B_TAG) == null) {
          manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root, new Frag_b(), FRAG_B_TAG).commit();
      } else {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag2 Already present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void closeFrag2() {
      Frag_b frag_b = (Frag_b) manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_B_TAG);

      if (frag_b != null) {
          manager.beginTransaction().remove(frag_b).commit();
      } else {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag2 Already not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

      }

  }
  }
  ```

In this code `manager.findFragByTag()` is being used to  check weather a fragment is already being displayed or not,since we only want to open one single instance of the other fragment. for its detailed use, see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#BackStack)

- Inside fragments, attach the mainActivity's class context to your handler obj and use it inside buttons:

  ```
  public class Frag_a extends Fragment {

      FragBHandler fragBHandler;

      public Frag_a() {
          // Required empty public constructor
      }

      @Override
      public void onAttach(Context context) {
          // context is the activity's context.
          super.onAttach(context);

          try {
              // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
              // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
              fragBHandler = (FragBHandler) context;
          } catch (ClassCastException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Log.e("", "onAttach: class has not implemented fragAhandler");
          }
      }
      // THIS SHOULD NEVER BE AN APPROCH.
      // public Frag_a(FragBHandler fragBHandler) {
      // this.fragBHandler = fragBHandler;
      // }

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          // Inflate the layout for this fragment
          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_a, container, false);
          v.findViewById(R.id.bt_open_frag2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  openFrag2();
              }
          });
          v.findViewById(R.id.bt_close_frag2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  closeFrag2();
              }
          });

          return v;
      }

      public void closeFrag2() {
          fragBHandler.closeFrag2();

      }

      public void openFrag2() {
          fragBHandler.addFrag2();

      }

  }
  ```

VOILA ,BOTH FRAGMENTS CAN LITERALLY TALK NOW!
**Part 3: Fragment Duplication **
this was one of the most difficult task.up till now, my aim to create an app with 2 fragments communicating was complete .But when i rotated my phone, there was a major fail: whatever that was present on the screen was being created multiple times!
[image]
I found the solution by doing the following things:
 - Using one common object for both frag1 and 2 that are created during onCreate(), and that too by checking if it is already present in the back-stack, then using that object only to add again.
 - Adding the initial fragment also after checking the back-stack.

So my final for mainActivity code becomes:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragAHandler, FragBHandler {
        LinearLayout layRoot;
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();


        Frag_a fragmentObjA;
        Frag_b fragmentObjB;
        public static final String FRAG_A_TAG = "FRAG_A";
        public static final String FRAG_B_TAG = "FRAG_B";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            initialise();

            if (manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG) == null && manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_B_TAG) == null) {
                //both are imp because of testcase not giving exact answer:
                // >>>open app: shows frag1>'press open frag2'>>>frg2 opens >'close frag 1' >>> rotate.
                //Expected output >> "fragment 2(already present object in backstack and on screen) to remain on screen
                //output recieved : both frag 1 and frg2 showing
                manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root, fragmentObjA, FRAG_A_TAG)
                        .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag1 Already present or fragment 2 present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        private void initialise() {
            layRoot = findViewById(R.id.layout_root);

            if(manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG)!=null){
                fragmentObjA= (Frag_a) manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG);
                Log.e(">>", "initialise: frgement A object recieved from the frag manager is used" );

            }
            else{
                Log.e(">>", "initialise:new frag a object created" );
                fragmentObjA=new Frag_a();

            }
            if(manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_B_TAG)!=null){
                fragmentObjB= (Frag_b) manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_B_TAG);

                Log.e(">>", "initialise: frgement B object recieved from the frag manager is used" );
            }
            else{
                Log.e(">>", "initialise:new frag object created" );
                fragmentObjB=new Frag_b();
            }
        }


        //-----------handler methods-------------------
        @Override
        public void addFrag1() {
            if (manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG) == null) {
                manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root, fragmentObjA, FRAG_A_TAG)
                        .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag1 Already present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void closeFrag1() {
            Frag_a fragA = (Frag_a) manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_A_TAG);
            if (fragA != null) {
                manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragA)
                        .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_EXIT_MASK)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag1 Already not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void addFrag2() {

            if (manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_B_TAG) == null) {
                manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.layout_root, fragmentObjB, FRAG_B_TAG)
                        .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag2 Already present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void closeFrag2() {
            Frag_b frag_b = (Frag_b) manager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_B_TAG);

            if (frag_b != null) {
                manager.beginTransaction().remove(frag_b)
                        .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_EXIT_MASK)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "frag2 Already not there", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }
```