# How to pass data from RecylcerAdapter to MainActivity through a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

as stated on the question, I am trying to pass data from the RecylerAdapter to the MainActivity, the only problem is when I use interfaces I can only pass it to the Fragment that creates the RecylcerView, any suggestions?

Comment: Do the same again.. now use an interface from the fragment to the activity. Or have some LiveData set in the fragment that is observed in the activity.

Comment: Just create a new listener interface for activity and then access this interface from your fragment (through onAttach or getActivity methods of the Fragment).  Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683615/4715901