# Viewpager2 and Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

```
ViewPager2 does not support direct child views
```

I'm trying to transition between fragments using the following code but I get the above error when using viewpager2.

**Call in fragment 1 to transition to fragment 2:**

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewPager2, new q2_fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**Viewpager2 XML in Main Layout:**

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

**Instantiation in Main:**

```
final ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(new QuestionsActivity.ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this));
        viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

How do I avoid this error with viewpager2?

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when I put the `TabLayout` before `ViewPager` 's closing tag

*That is:*

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
```

**Which is not Allowed!**

Just Removing the ending tag and separating `TabLayout` will work

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Would be happy to help, please elaborate on your requirement. What exactly you want to do.

If you want to go to `fragment 2` from  `fragment 1`, at a particular point then you should use `interface` between fragment and activity, to tell the activity to move the `viewpager` to the item which has `fragment 2`.

[Interface Pattern for Fragment to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683615/9701793)

Interface

```
public interface FragmentCallback{
    public void goTo(int pos);
}
```

Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyStringListener{

  @Override
  public void goTo(int pos){
        yourviewpagerAdapter.setCurrentItem(pos);
  }

}

public class Fragment1 {

        private FragmentCallback callBack;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            try {
                callBack = (FragmentCallback) context;
            } catch (ClassCastException castException) {
                /** The activity does not implement the listener. */
            }
        }

       

        public void someEvent() {
            if(callBack!=null) {
                callBack.goTo(1);
            } 
        }           

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not recall the specific problem I was facing other than what I stated in this post, but I do believe interfacing is the way to go and what I eventually ended up using in the app I was working on.

Comment: @MAF hope the answer helped you, and ill appreciate it if you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the statement says

`ViewPager2 does not support direct child views`
So never try to add the fragment to viewPager2 **directly**
i.e the following lines of code will not work with viewPager2.

```js
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewPager2, new q2_fragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

The exception is produced if you try to add fragment directly to viewPager2 with the help of `fragmentManager`.
So simply remove the above lines of code to get rid of this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Lets Say From `Fragment_1` to `Fragment_2`:

**In side the button click in `Fragment_1`**

```java
Bundle result = new Bundle(); result.putString("bundleKey", "result"); getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("requestKey", result);
```

**In side the  `Fragment_2`  `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method**

```java
getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("requestKey", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
 @Override public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle)
 { 
supported String result = bundle.getString("bundleKey"); System.out.println("----------------------------"+result); 
}
 });
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-between-fragments

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#pass-between-fragments

Answer (score -1):

Use  mPager.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

Comment: Please provide more details: why/how your suggestion works? How it addresses the original issue?