how to make a Bluetooth connection for all fragments?
I can't make bluetooth connected for all fragments, you need to connect to all fragments once.

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
class BluetoothController(private val adapter: BluetoothAdapter) {
    private var connectThread: ConnectThread? = null

    fun connect(mac: String, listener: Listener){
        if(adapter.isEnabled && mac.isNotEmpty()){
            val device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(mac)
            connectThread = ConnectThread(device, listener)
            connectThread?.start()
        }
    }
    fun sendMessage(message: String){
        connectThread?.sendMessage(message)
    }

    fun closeConnection(){
        connectThread?.closeConnection()
    }
    companion object{
        const val BLUETOOTH_CONNECTED = "Bluetooth соединение подключено"
        const val BLUETOOTH_NO_CONNECTED = "Bluetooth соединение отключено"
    }
    interface Listener{
        fun onReceive(message: String)
    }
}

 else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_bt_connect) { // Подключение к ESP32.
                bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this@MainFragment)
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Подключение к маяку", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

 else if (item.itemId == R.id.id_bt_connect) { // Подключение к ESP32.
                bluetoothController.connect(mac ?: "", this@ColorGlow)
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Подключение к маяку", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


I don`t know
for some reason, the problem is not solved, when switching to another fragment, the Bluetooth connection is lost, and it is not possible to make a Bluetooth connection to all fragments at once.

"I can't make bluetooth connected for all fragments" How about having just one connection all the time in the Activity and delegating any Bluetooth work to the Activity?

how do it??????

Fragments can get a reference to their parent Activity with the getActivity() method. Some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659747/call-an-activity-method-from-a-fragment
